# Test cases execution in python

Tags: python, automation

I have writen simple code to validate csv and oracle data but getting processed finished with exit code 0. when i check in 2nd file method not calling properly from first file.

here two file code. pls check and let me know what are the mistake i did.

**test_cases_lps**

```
import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd

class TestCases:
    def tc_verify_filecount_tablecount_validation_1(self):
        try:
            df_dept = pd.read_csv('E:/Python/practice/lps/data/deptv.csv')
            print(df_dept)
            print(df_dept.columns)
            print(df_dept.dttypes)

            sql = '''select * from deptv'''
            print(sql)
            df_table = pd.read_sql(sql, con=('scott/tiger@localhost'))
            print(df_table)

            assert len(df_dept.index) == len(df_table.index)
        except Exception as err:
            print('Both are not match', err)


def main():
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

**test_runner_lps**

```
import sys

import lps.testcase.test_cases_lps as test_cases
from lps.testcase.test_cases_lps import TestCases

test_cases.main()
tc = TestCases()


@classmethod
def test_tc_verify_filecount_tablecount_validation_1():
    try:
        tc.tc_verify_filecount_tablecount_validation_1()
        print("pass")
        print("abc", '1', '1', True)

    except Exception as err:
        print('Test case failed', err)


def main():
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to update def tc_verify_filecount_tablecount_validation_1(self) on:

```
def test_verify_filecount_tablecount_validation_1(self):
```

and run via cli like:

```
python test_runner_lps.py
```